# Limitations of running kdb+ 32-bit version

Tags: kdb

Now that the 32-bit version of kdb+ has been made free for commercial use by kx, what benefits are there still to buying a licence, other than:

1. 64-bit version will allow you to address more than 4GB of memory
2. You will get support and access to a members-only mailing list

Specifically, will operations on 64-bit datatype vectors (long and float) be slower with the 32-bit interpreter, or can it utilize the full word size of the CPU?

Comment: somewhat similar to this question--> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840510/what-performance-can-we-expect-from-kdb-32bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840510/what-performance-can-we-expect-from-kdb-32bit)